# Python error when running project

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, macos-high-sierra

I have an error when running one of my projects, and it is very strange.    What happens is this:

```
 File "src/run.py", line 4, in <module>
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
ImportError: No module named dotenv
```

The strange thing is that I have installed python-dotenv.
This is the fourth line:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Running High Sierra with python 2.7.

Comment: Is it the default Python or a custom Python installation?

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH` and where exactly are the module's files installed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you have have installed `dotenv` for another python distribution.

You can try to run the two following commands that use the same python program to install and run `python-dotenv`. The first one installs `python-dotenv` with `pip`. The second one tests the install. I use `sudo` to install it with main `python` program.

```
sudo python -m pip install python-dotenv
python -c 'from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv'
```

It works also with Python3 (where you do not have to run the install command with `sudo`)

```
python3 -m pip install python-dotenv
python3 -c 'from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv'
```